# how to retrieve array if hidden fields from jsp to action class in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I am using Struts2 framework to retrieve data from database and display as links. The below code code creates such links.

```
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    HospitalUserVo vo = itr.next();
%>
    <tr>
        <s:set var="i_"><%= i %></s:set>
        <td><s:hidden  name="index" value="%{#i_}"></s:hidden></td>
        <s:set var="id_"><%= vo.getHospitalUserId() %></s:set>
        <td><s:hidden  name="id[%{#i_}]" value="%{#id_}"></s:hidden></td>
        <td><a href="<s:url action='viewHospitalUser'/>"><%out.print(vo.getHospitalUserId());%></a></td>
        <td><% out.print(vo.getHospitalUserFirstName()); 
%></td>
```

And in the action class, I am using a member variable `private String[] id;` with getter and setter methods. Also, in the `execute()` method, I am calling `getId();` to retrieve the data from the jsp.

However, `getId()` is always returning null.

Can anybody let me know what is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. Use tags instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the `id` as parameter.

```
<a href="<s:url action='viewHospitalUser'><s:param name='id' value='%{#id_}'/></s:url>">
```

Comment: @Jagannadha You should accept the answer that helped you. If you don't know how to do that see http://stackoverflow.com/tour